# RT 60 from Impulse response

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, impulse-response, sound, acoustics

I have already the impulse response of an acoustic environment in the form of a series of signals over 300 samples. I have tried the procedure given in this platform - i.e. low pass filtering, Hilbert transform and then calculating the energy etc... However, Im unable to to get the RT 60.
Can you send me the exact Matlab codes for each of the different steps?

Regards,

Sajaad

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17121/calculation-of-reverberation-time-rt60-from-the-impulse-response/17123#17123 calculate the slope of the energy decay curve and you'll find RT60

Comment: What's your sample rate? For RT60 calculation you typically need way more samples than 300.